# sql order by? how do you select the last 25 rows added?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i save a new rows .. and it is saved so

id, user, message
i want to get the last 25 saved
but whit this

```
select top 25 usuario, mensaje 
from chat  
order by idchat asc
```

I just get the first 25, how can i get the last 25 rows?

the table is it

```
create table chat
(idchat int primary key identity,
usuario varchar(50),
mensaje text);
```

if i execute

```
select top 25 usuario, mensaje from chat  order by idchat desc
```

it return a bad thing.. for example i a saved

```
'user1','mensaje1'
'user1','mensaje2'
'user1', 'mensaje3'
```

this returns

```
'user1','mensaje3'
'user1','mensaje2'
'user1', 'mensaje1'
```

I dont need it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change ASC to DESC:

```
select top 25 usuario, mensaje from chat  order by idchat desc
```

Edit: you want the last 25, but after filtering for the last 25, you want them ordered ascending?

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    select top 25 
        usuario, 
        mensaje 
    from 
        chat  
    order by 
        idchat desc
    )
ORDER BY
  idchat ASC
```

Comment: select * from (select top  25 * from chat order by idchat desc) as chat1
order by chat1.idchat asc

Comment: Yeah, I just posted an edit with something similar.  You want the last 25, but ordered ascending once filtered.